# Running a set of Ruby scripts in Terminal

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

I want to repetitively run a Ruby script in the Mac Terminal window that does a text search on a text file.  The script works well on each text file at a time in Terminal, but I want to do this multiple times on a sequence of files.

I've tried creating a script in automator but no luck.  As an FYI the Ruby script is attached, but that is not the issue

Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'yaml'
require 'csv'
abort "You must specify one or more files to search." if ARGV.size == 0

search_terms = "---
:stage1:
  JTSJ3:
  - text term 1
:stage2n:
  JTSJ3:
  - nothing
:stage2p:
  JTSJ3:
  - text term 2
:stage3:
  JTSJ3:
  - nothing"

...
File.open(File.join(result_dir, 'results_stage3.yml'), 'w') do |f|
  f.write stage3_results.to_yaml
end
File.open(File.join(result_dir, 'results_stage3.csv'), 'w') do |f|
  f.write csv_header.to_csv
  stage3_results.each do |r|
    f.write [ r[:category], r[:term], r[:line], r[:text], r[:file] ].to_csv
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few patterns you can use here, but to employ these techniques the key is to define a simple entry point method that you can call as necessary instead of having all that stuff just strewn about in the `main` namespace.

Pull filenames from the `ARGV` arguments list:

```
ARGV.each do |file|
  process(file)
end
```

You can use `File.basename(file, '.yml')` to strip off extensions and switch that to `.csv` if you prefer. Keep your method as generic as possible.

Secondly, you can use `xargs` externally:

```
find . -name '*.yml' | xargs ruby program.rb
```

Where that will append all the files matching that pattern as arguments to your program. You can even tweak the options to run in parallel:

```
find . -name '*.yml' | xargs -n 2 -p 8 ruby program.rb
```

Where that runs 8 parallel processes (`-p 8`), each processing up to two files (`-n 2`).

You can also do this yourself with:

```
Dir.glob('source_dir/**/*.yml') do |file|
  process(file)
end
```

Where `Dir.glob` is great at finding a lot of things. To parallelize that you can either use threads or forking. `xargs` is a quick way to get that all for "free".